# How to link one array value to another array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called `category`.

```
var category =  ["automobile","Fashion","Music Instruments"]
```

and I need to link this array with the below array according to product.

```
var products = ["LandRover","Guitar","vintage,"Drums","Maserati","Piano"]
```

Comment: Give us what have you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "link"?  Perhaps you can describe what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Kind of binary tree or hyperlink

Comment: _Kind of binary tree or hyperlink._ Still unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about some stuff like this?...

```
//variables predefined
var category = ["Automobile","Fashion","Music Instruments"]
var products = ["LandRover","Guitar","vintage","Drums","Maserati","Piano"]

//create a object categories where later we will add our products!
var categories = { };   

//add values(category & products)
categories[ category[0] ] = [ products[0] , products[4] ];              //Automobile
categories[ category[1] ] = [ products[2] ];               //Fashion
categories[ category[2] ] = [ products[1] , products[3] ,products[5]  ];     //Music Instrument
```

So now if you wanna display some value of 'automobile' for example, just:

```
//METHOD1
categories['automobile']
//METHOD2
categories[ category[0] ]     //category[0]->automobile
```

And what you get is the array with all the products of category,so you just have to choose wich one you want.
Here you can see what you have got in console.

[image]

Function for show it in some HTML ( void html i hope)

```
function showObjectOnHTML( obj ){
   for (var key in categories) {   //check categories of thethe object
       if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

           var CATEGORIES = key;
           var SPAN = document.createElement('SPAN');
           SPAN.setAttribute('style','font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 5px; display:block;');
           SPAN.appendChild( document.createTextNode( CATEGORIES ) );
           document.body.appendChild(SPAN);

           var PRODUCTS = categories[key];
           for( var i=0; i<PRODUCTS.length; i++){
               var SPAN = document.createElement('SPAN');
               SPAN.setAttribute('style','margin-left: 15px;font-size: 20px; display:block;');
               SPAN.appendChild( document.createTextNode( PRODUCTS[i] ) );
               document.body.appendChild(SPAN);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

For show it,just type,:

```
 showObjectOnHTML(categories);
```

[image]

Comment: Yh. Thanks for understanding my problem. This code helps me.

Comment: But I am not allowed to vote now as I am not the citizen of stackoverflow.. haha.. I am new in stackoverflow due to this currently I am not having right to vote

Comment: I want to improve the display look. like:

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: are you talking about the image? is using -> console.log(categories)

Comment: Automobile("bold" letter)
    LandRover
    Mazda
Music Instruments("bold" letter)
    Guitar
    Drums
Fashion("bold" letter)
   Vintage
   StreetWear

Comment: i.e. with proper bullets & font (bold & etc)

Comment: oh, you talking about display it on some HTML?, well just add to CSS, font-weight: bold; ... if you want i add it, share your HTML file then i can see where use it;) but thats not a 'big problem'

Comment: because you wanna display it on some HTML file right?

Comment: hi. did u get solution?

Comment: yes, i already put it, in the answer, check again my answer in the TOp

Comment: & another thing is. Suppose I'll remove fashion in array by coding. Then Vintage also get removed but automatically. How to do this?

Comment: you just have to remove the line where add that category, you can't do it automatically, i mean, theres no way that the program understand that 'vintage' is a 'fashion', so just remove this lines ->
*categories[ category[1] ] = [ products[2] ];
and change this one
*categories[ category[2] ] = [ products[1] , products[3] ,products[5]  ]; by this one -> *categories[ category[1] ] = [ products[1] , products[3] ,products[5]  ];

Comment: Hi. Initial solution what you had provided me. In that, I want to make category array as dynamically i.e. If I am adding element in category array, it should display automatically. How to go through this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is an object (used like a "hashmap" in java):

```
//set examples
var category = {
    automobile: [],
    fashion: [],
    musicInstuments: ["Piano"]
};

category["automobile"] = category["automobile"].concat(["LandRover", "Maserati"]);
category.fashion.push("Vintage");


//get examples
for(var key in category){
    category[key].forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
    });
}

console.log(category.automobile[0]);
```

Using an object will also give you constant access time to the category you are looking for (instead of iterating over n items to find it)

Comment: I want to display according to category name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use objects instead of only lists?

```
var categories = [
    { 
       name: "Automobile",
       products: ["LandRover", "Maserati"]
    },
    { 
       name: "Fashion",
       products: ["Vintage"]
    },
    { 
       name: "Music Instruments",
       products: ["Guitar", "Drums", "Piano"]
    }
]
```

Also, like someone commented, what exactly do you want to accomplish?

**EDIT**

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/gmc33evs/1/) JSFiddle shows one way to list products in each category using AngularJS.

Comment: I just want to display products according to respective category.

Comment: In this scenario, I want to display it according to name.

Comment: Can you tell me how to display it according to name

Comment: I have updated my answer with a JSFiddle for one way to display the data using AngularJS.